# Getting the userID in Actions on Google

Tags: permissions, actions-on-google, userid

On the [Actions on Google site](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/user-info) I find a function for getting the userID to identify a user across conversations and devices. In the [docs section under getUser](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/AssistantApp#getUser) I read following:

> getUser() returns User
>
> Gets the User object. The user object contains information about the
>   user, including a string identifier and personal information (requires
>   requesting permissions, see askForPermissions).

So first i need to request permission. For this i follow the link. But there i find only three permission that can be request.

- NAME
- DEVICE_COARSE_LOCATION
- DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION

Theres no permission to granted for the userID. And when i run my code and try getting the userID it return undefined. Getting the userName works fine.

```
function requestPermissonsIntent(app){
    const permission = [app.SupportedPermissions.NAME];
    app.askForPermission('Für eine korrekte Ausführung', permission);
}

//later in my code when asking for the userID and userName
if(app.isPermissionGranted()){
      const userName = app.getUserName().displayName;
      //getting the userName works fine

      const userUID = app.getUser().userID;
      //userUID is undefinded
      ...
```

How can I get the UserID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be a lowercase "d".

```
app.getUser().userId;
```

You don't need to ask for any permission to get this userId. The string identifier returned is unique for this user in your Action. It should carry across devices if they use the same account.

**Update**

This has been deprecated as of May 2018, and is scheduled to be discontinued in May 2019.

If you need a userid, you have a few options:

- Create your own userid and save it in the [user storage](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/save-data#save_data_across_conversations) object, which will persist between conversations. (Users can empty this storage at any time, however.)
- Use [Google Sign In for Assistant](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in), which lets the user grant permission for you to get their Google ID, along with other profile information, every time your webhook is called.

Comment: Shame on me. Sometimes its so easy. I had read my code for many times but did not find this mistake. So now that i get the userId  i updated my question. Is there a way to memory that the user granted the permission?

Comment: That really is a separate question. Go ahead and ask it as a new SO question and we'll be happy to answer.

Comment: (And the lowercase-d is easy to miss. I've done it many times myself.)

Comment: @Prisoner : I just found that this `unique user id` can save into `User Storage` for working among conversations. But it need permission in Google Home application, after clicked [`Allow My Service to remember me`](https://support.google.com/assistant/answer/7510256). 

Therefore, in case after clicked `Stop My Service to remember me`, we can not save userId to User Storage, so even using same account, it can not pass `unique user id` among conversations, right?

Comment: Yes, users can turn this off if they choose. In this case, you will see a new user ID each time. (Also note that this feature has been deprecated. See the update.)